# Flutter::AAR files cannot be found by gradle

Tags: flutter, aar

I tried to created a new Android Application using Flutter and want to use some third party library to implement calling function. However, it seem my gradle cannot find my AAR file located on libs folder under APP level directory. Can anyone show me if I'm doing it wrong

Console Output:
[image: Console Output]

Gradle File:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.ems.ern_2"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(name: 'DeltapathMobileSDK-release', ext: 'aar')
    implementation(name: 'DeltapathMobileCallSDK-release', ext: 'aar')
    implementation(name: 'DeltapathMobileChatSDK-release', ext: 'aar')
}


flutter {
    source '../..'
}
```

Project Structure where AAR file located:
[image: Project Structure]

AndroidManifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ems.ern_2">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

   <application
        android:label="ern_2"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
       <service
           android:name=".service.SdkService"
           android:enabled="true"
           android:exported="true"></service>
       <service
           android:name=".service.CallSdkService"
           android:enabled="true"
           android:exported="true" />

       <activity android:name=".call.CallSdkActivity" />
       <activity android:name=".chat.ChatSdkActivity"></activity>

       <service
           android:name=".service.SdkService"
           android:enabled="true"
           android:exported="true" />
       <service
           android:name=".service.ChatSdkService"
           android:enabled="true"
           android:exported="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       <activity android:name=".call.CallActivity"/>
       <activity android:name=".call.CallListActivity"/>
       <activity android:name=".call.IncomingCallScreenActivity"/>
       <activity android:name=".chat.ChatActivity"/>
       <activity android:name=".chat.GroupChatOptionsActivity"/>
       <activity android:name=".chat.ChatRoomActivity"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I've tried create a new project and proceed to include AAR file into my file without touching other file except for AndroidManifest and Gradle. However still failed to run

Answer (score 0):

run the following commands:

```
cd android
./gradlew clear
./gradlew build
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

and try running again

Comment: I've tried this and still got error [console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJUXO.png)

Comment: delete and reinstall android SDK from SDK Manager

Comment: It successfully build and run the app. However, I cannot import the class. Package com.deltapath.deltapathmobilesdk.call does not exist

Comment: please raise a new question with appropriate details. Do close this as answered.